# Paragraph floating out of a container

Tags: html, css

I have created a container to centre my content to the middle of the page, and I have an issue where the paragraph tags continue out of the container div and do not wrap automatically. I always found that the container worked with a wrap, and I've never had problems with this.

```
.container { width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

This is the HTML floating out of the div.container element

```
<div class="container">
    <p>TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you have no breaking characters inside the `<p>` element.

Comment: use percentages instead of hard coded px values. `width:1000px` -> `width:100%`

Comment: @Alpay that makes no sense

Comment: I am sorry I got the question wrong. The reason why your string continues out of the container is, your string doesn't have any space characters and html parser can' t know where to break this string down. So for this case, you have to use `word-wrap: break-word;` CSS attribute as suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is because the text inside `<p>` is a word with no spaces, you can force a word wrap with the following rule:

```
.container {
  word-wrap: break-word; /* Forces to wrap the word and cut it*/
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This won't work on an old browser so be carefull, another approach is to hide the extending text with a `overflow: hidden` attribute.

Comment: What if I want to break a line at the end of a word so we don't break the actual word, but the line?

Comment: If there are no spaces, how do you know where the word ends?

Comment: if your word has spaces the browser will automatically break it without applying any rule.

Comment: Great, I didn't actually know this, feel bald now haha. We learn new things everyday :P

Answer (score 1):

Add these properties:

```
overflow:hidden;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

The link to working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BAjaZ/embedded/result/) with width set to **100px** is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BAjaZ/embedded/result/).